# How to restrict access to Elastic Search cluster with Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-amplify

I created an Elastic Search cluster on AWS and I need to configure access control. I have an Amplify app that has a custom Lambda which will verify the incoming request based on user and cross check in Cognito if that user exists. Then only fetch documents from ES cluster that match a specific field name for this specific user. I saw there is configuration available when launching ES cluster in management console like Amazon Cognito authentication. Is that what I need, or do I need Custom access policy or JSON defined access policy? I dont want public access to ES.